# React/HTML5: How to avoid details tag from being wrapped to next row after openning it?

Tags: css, html

**Hello and thank you for your time!**

I am learning how to use flex and React.

I am facing a curious situation. Currently there is a detail component which aim is to open/close controls:

```
<details className="spaced-column" style={{
                        backgroundColor: "green",
                        flexWrap: "nowrap"
                    }}>
                        <summary>Controles</summary>

                        <div>
                            <Dropdown options={this.options} onChange={this._onSelect}
                                      placeholder="Select an option"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="chbox1" value="1"/>Option 1</label>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="chbox2" value="2"/>Option 2</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="chbox3" value="3"/>Option 3</label>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="chbox4" value="4"/>Option 4</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="column-right-aligned">
                            <Button incrementValue={1} onClickFunction={this.incrementCounter}/>
                            <Button incrementValue={5} onClickFunction={this.incrementCounter}/>
                            <Button incrementValue={10} onClickFunction={this.incrementCounter}/>
                            <Button incrementValue={100} onClickFunction={this.incrementCounter}/>
                            <Result counter={this.state.counter}/>

                        </div>
                    </details>
```

Also, spaced-column class is:

```
.spaced-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

***The need is to keep the component in the same row***

Currently when we open the details flow to the next row.

When window is at maximum size, details are the green div on the right:
[image]

When details are opened they still in the same row:
[image]

When we resize, the controls either close or opened flow to the next row:
[image]

I have read for further details: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp

So then I tried, as you saw on the photos and code, to use:

```
style{{flexWrap:"nowrap"}}
```

I susspect that it could be related to gray and yellow divs (which are canvas) and have their size using the viewport as:

```
.imgPreview {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px 15px;
    height: 80vh;
    width: 40vw;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    border-top: 5px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000000;
}
```

Would you mind to help me to solve this question? I would appreciate an explanation more than the solution itself!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution but I do not understand it well, it was just pure try and error:

The full code of the two canvas and details:

```
 <main>
        <header>
            <h3>Suba una imagen desde el ordenador, para mostrarla:</h3>
        </header>
        <article className="multi-line-no-spaced-row">
            <section className="multi-line-row">
                < section className="spaced-column" style={{
                    backgroundColor: 'gray',
                }}>
                    <ImageUpload onChange={this.setFileFromUrl} file={this.state.file}
                                 upload={this.state.upload}/>
                </section>
                <section className="spaced-column" style={{
                    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
                }}>
                    <ImageUpload onChange={this.setFileFromUrl} file={this.state.file}
                                 upload={this.state.upload}/>
                </section>
            </section>
            <details className="spaced-column" style={{
                backgroundColor: "green",
                flexWrap: "nowrap"
            }}>
                <summary>Controles</summary>

                <div>
                    <Dropdown options={this.options} onChange={this._onSelect}
                              placeholder="Select an option"/>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chbox1" value="1"/>Option 1</label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chbox2" value="2"/>Option 2</label>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chbox3" value="3"/>Option 3</label>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chbox4" value="4"/>Option 4</label>
                </div>
                <div className="column-right-aligned">
                    <Button incrementValue={1} onClickFunction={this.incrementCounter}/>
                    <Button incrementValue={5} onClickFunction={this.incrementCounter}/>
                    <Button incrementValue={10} onClickFunction={this.incrementCounter}/>
                    <Button incrementValue={100} onClickFunction={this.incrementCounter}/>
                    <Result counter={this.state.counter}/>

                </div>
            </details>
```

Also the CSS classes:

```
.multi-line-row {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.multi-line-no-spaced-row {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.spaced-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

So then, as you would imagine I just changed flex-wrap: nowrap; to both rows:

```
.multi-line-row {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.multi-line-no-spaced-row {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Also I do not like how detail's children look cramped:
[image]

***How could we expand the detail's width to full size, to make it ocuppy al the width after opening it?***